# RJSONIO failed loading an array

Tags: json, r

Hi I am using RJSONIO to load a json file, test.json, which has a quite simple structure like:

```
{
   "exps" :   [
    {   
        "model" : "lm",
        "featTran" : false,
        "factor" : true
    },
    {
        "model" : "J48",
        "featTran" : true,
        "factor" : true
    },
    {
        "model" : "NULL"
    }   
    ]
}
```

The loading command is just:

```
    config<-fromJSON(file("./test.json", "r"))
```

When adding the third object in the array ("NULL" model), RJSONIO just returns a blank list().
However, when only using the first two objects, the loading has no problem.

Comment: Hm, actually both gives me a blank list here. Are you sure the reading with just the first two elements runs ok?

Comment: It seems there's some problem with reading arrays. I couldn't read any JSON file with an array into R. However I succeeded in reading JSON files without arrays. Anyone made it?

Comment: Thanks for this finding. I will switch to a hash table to see the effect.

Comment: I just switched to use another R package, rjson. `config<-fromJSON(paste(readLines("test.json"), collapse=""))`. rjson can allow me to load my array (even with three objects) without any issue.

Comment: I was trying to use exactly this code, that I found on another question, but without success. That's it, this 'fromJSON' function is from a different package. ;)